# Taxes due for hobbyist Group Buy

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-profit

I am part of a hobby forum and I am running a non-profit group buy.  I'm a little worried how that will influence my taxes.

The group buy works as such: One member wants something expensive, so he gets a bunch of other members to get together who want the same item.  They all chip in and give the money to the original person, who then makes a bulk purchase at a discount.  The original member then distributes the items to the rest of the participants.  My example is a non-profit version.  Some people choose to charge a small fee for the amount of work that goes into organizing the group buy.  That would be a for-profit group buy.

My case involves the following:  I'm in the US.  I have about 120 people on board for my group buy, and the total money brought in is about $10,000.  I set up a Paypal business account to simplify invoicing people for what they order.  Each person pays via Paypal, and I make the purchase.  Some parts are coming from an international supplier, some are coming from local suppliers.  When I receive the goods, they will be sent by mail to the participants.  The entirety of what they spent will go toward the purchase from the supplier and the shipping.  Some have elected to send me donations to cover any overages/thank me for doing the leg work.  All of the money +/- donations is being used for the group, and none of it (outside of whatever is left from donations) will return to me as a profit.

How do I go about explaining this on my taxes?

I'm worried I will get hit pretty hard.  From an outsider's perspective, it appears that I have made $10k and then spent it on big purchases.  Compared to my actual source of income (grad student), $10k is about 1/3 of what I actually make before taxes.I'm not doing it for profit, so I'm not a business.  I currently have no registration as an LLC outside of being signed up for the Paypal Business version of the site, which should not have implications.

Answer (score 6):

From the poster's description of this activity, it doesn't look like he is engaged in a business, so Schedule C would not be appropriate. The first paragraph of the [IRS Instructions for Schedule C](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sc.pdf) is as follows:

> Use Schedule C (Form 1040) to report income or loss from a business
>   you operated or a profession you practiced as a sole proprietor. An
>   activity qualifies as a business if your primary purpose for engaging
>   in the activity is for income or profit and you are involved in the
>   activity with continuity and regularity. For example, a sporadic
>   activity or a hobby does not qualify as a business. To report income
>   from a nonbusiness activity, see the instructions for Form 1040, line
>   21, or Form 1040NR, line 21.

What the poster is doing is acting as a nominee or agent for his members. For instance, if I give you $3.00 and ask you to go into Starbucks and buy me a pumpkin-spice latte, you do not have income or receipts of $3.00, and you are not engaged in a business. The amounts that the poster's members are forwarding him are like this.

Money that the poster receives for his trouble should be reported as nonbusiness income on Line 21 of Form 1040, in accordance with the instructions quoted above and the instructions for Form 1040.

Finally, it should be noted that the poster cannot take deductions or losses relating to this activity. So he can't deduct any expenses of organizing the group buy on his tax return. Of course, this would not be the case if the group buy really is the poster's business and not just a "hobby."

Of course, it goes without saying that the poster should document all of this activity with receipts, contemporaneous emails (and if available, contracts) - as well as anything else that could possibly be relevant to proving the nature of this activity in the event of an audit.

Comment: That's actually not really helpful to the OP. Consider he actually does have profits, and that the hobby income deductions are limited by the AGI 2% threshold. The OP will probably be better off with Schedule C.

Comment: The IRS says not to use Schedule C for this kind of income literally in the *first paragraph* of its instructions for Schedule C. How will OP be better off by not following the IRS's own guidance on the issue?

Comment: The IRS can say whatever they want, the taxpayer is the one deciding in this case. As I said - hobby income deductions are limited, Schedule C are not. He has $10K income and *almost* $10K expenses, but with hobby income his *deductible* expenses will be lower.

Comment: I agree 100% that the tax treatment of business losses is better than hobby losses. That's why when the IRS audits people on this issue, the IRS argues that taxpayers' activities are hobbies, and not the other way around. But taxpayers do not have an _election_ regarding whether their activities are hobbies or businesses--They have to follow the **law.** If OP reports his group buy as if it's a valid business, then he risks being assessed interest and penalties if the issue ever comes up on audit.

Comment: @Heath Thanks for the input of the non-business 1040 line 21 info.  It would seem that fits best with the letter of the law.

Comment: @littleadv You raise the exact point of my question.  The Schedule C approach does make sense.  However, I am taking great pains to not make any profit from the transactions as the donations were documented as a separate line 'gift'.  While it is tempting to deduct my expenses, it might cause more trouble.

Comment: @WesH in what way? Worst case would be the IRS *forcing* you to give up deductions, but why would you voluntarily give it up? I see no reason, from the fact pattern  you presented, to voluntarily pay more tax. There's no law that requires you to use line 21, and despite Heath's suggestion to otherwise - there's no law preventing you from using Schedule C for hobby income. The only case when it is not advisable is when you have *loss*, which is not your case. The law doesn't allow deducting losses, not expenses.

Comment: @WesH *as the donations were documented as a separate line 'gift'.* -- **THAT** is breaking the law. There's no "gift" here. This is clearly compensation for your services.

Comment: @littleadv There is no need for me to take a deduction, my actual income is extremely low and my IRA contributions cover me pretty well.  Additionally, according to the IRS Instructions Heath posted, my hobby does not count as a business.

I intend to claim the donations received as gifts as miscellaneous income.  Donations came from a small percentage of the participants in the group buy, and I stated clearly beforehand that it was not required.  Therefore my sole intent in that case was not profit, making it excused from Schedule C.

Comment: @WesH if you claim that either way is tax neutral - then do whatever is most convenient. Usually, when it is not tax neutral - Schedule C would be better

Comment: @littleadv I agree that Schedule C would be very useful if I needed to claim and it was appropriate.  That's why I thanked you and gave your answer a +1.  However, Heath's answer is probably most convenient and appropriate in my case.

Comment: BTW, the law clearly requires taxpayers to follow IRS instructions and forms when making a tax return. In the words of the U.S. Supreme Court, "Congress has given discretion to the Commissioner to prescribe by regulation forms of returns and has made it the duty of the taxpayer to comply." [Comm'r v. Lane Wells Co., 321 U.S. 219 (1944)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/321/219/case.html). If a taxpayer files a return that does not follow the rules, he runs a risk that the statute of limitations will not start to run and that the IRS will impose penalties and interest.

Answer (score 3):

You do actually have some profits (*whatever is left from donations*).

The way it goes is that you report everything on your Schedule C. You will report this:

1. Gross receipts (line 1) - all the money you got from the group (excluding the money you put in yourself, but including all the "donations").
2. Cost of goods (line 4) - all the money you spent on purchasing and shipping (excluding the items you kept for yourself)
3. Gross profits - the difference between the two amounts.

Your gross profits will then flow to Net Profit (line 31) since you had no other expenses (unless you had some other expenses, like paypal fees, which will appear in the relevant category in part II), and from line 31 it will go to your 1040 for the final tax calculation.